# MySQL Appender not inserting data in database in Log4Net

Tags: c#, mysql, configuration, log4net

It doesn't show any errors anymore, but it also doesn't insert anything into the MySQL database. Any ideas? I replaced my login information with dummy text.

**Edit**

There is an error about the connection type.

```
log4net:ERROR [AdoNetAppender] ErrorCode: GenericFailure. Failed to load connection type [MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection, MySql.Data, Version=5.5.47, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d]
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=5.5.47, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'MySql.Data, Version=5.5.47, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d'
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName)
   at System.RuntimeType.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
   at log4net.Util.SystemInfo.GetTypeFromString(Assembly relativeAssembly, String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
   at log4net.Util.SystemInfo.GetTypeFromString(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
   at log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender.ResolveConnectionType()
```

**This is my `App.config` file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
  </configSections>

  <log4net>
    <!-- appenders here -->

    <appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
      <bufferSize value="1" />
      <connectionType value="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection, MySql.Data, Version=5.5.47, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
      <connectionString value="Server=myhost;Database=mydb;UID=myuser;Password=mypassword" />
      <commandText value="INSERT INTO mylog (date) VALUES (?date)" />
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="date" />
        <dbType value="DateTime" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
      </parameter>
    </appender>


    <root>
      <level value="Debug"/>
      <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
      <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
      <appender-ref ref="ADONetAppender" />
      <appender-ref ref="SmtpAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>

  <startup> 
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6"/>
  </startup>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Edit: There is an error, I updated my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the MySQL.Data dll or a dependency in your bin directory. Likely is that you have no direct reference in your project and because of that it is not copied. Make a reference and make sure it is copied into your bin directory.

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking it would be something like this. From where do I get the proper Data DLL file?